# Yii2 Codeception issue in Advanced Template

Tags: codeception

I am having difficulties with setting up Codeception under the Yii2 Advanced App.
The README.md in [approot]/tests (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/tests/README.md)
tells me to do this (step 5):

```
cd backend (this puts me into approot/tests/codeception/backend/)
codecept build
```

This leads to this response in the terminal:

```
Building Actor classes for suites: unit, acceptance, functional
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
Codeception\Lib\Generator\Actor::getGuy() in phar:///home/alex/codecept/src/Codeception/Command/Build.php on line 46
```

I thought this had to do with the Global version of codeception having a different version than the one in vendor/bin, but that's not the case (am using version 2.0.5 of codeception).

Have I got a wrong configuration someplace else?

Thanks for your help anyone!
Alex

Comment: Why do you use 2.0.5? Upgrade to 2.0.16 or even better to 2.1.4.

Comment: It is very likely that your issue was caused by having different versions of Codeception. 2.0.5 was the last version which had getGuy method in Codeception\Lib\Generator\Actor class.

Comment: Thanks Naktibalda, I wasn't aware of using an older version. The issue was that on my system, codecept was linked to an outdated binary. Adding ~/.composer/vendor to my $PATH did the trick, and started using 2.1.4 instead.